# LocalStorage keeps bringing back removed values

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am using local storage API to store items in the cart, but i am having a problem with it. At first when i add an item into it, it works normally and also when i remove the item is works normally. but when i try to add one item to the cart, the localStorage brings back all the removed items.

There are two function below,

- `AddToCart()` – to add item from the home and single product page,
- `removeFromCart()` – remove item from the cart.

```js
function AddToCart(){
  // Home page 
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('zysod_cart'))
  $('.addcart').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this).closest('.single-product-content')
    var productId = parseInt($this.attr('data-product-id'))
    var productName = $this.find('.product-title').text()
    var productImg = $this.attr('data-product-src')
    var productPrice = $this.find('.product-price .regular-price').text()
    var found = data.products.some(function(el){
      return parseInt(el.id) === productId
    })

    if (!found) {
      data.items = parseInt(data.items) + 1;          
      data.products.push({
        id: productId,
        name: productName,
        quantity: 1,
        image: productImg,
        price: productPrice
      });
      var total = 0
      for(var item in data.products){
        total += (data.products[item].price === 'Price not available'? 0 : parseInt(data.products[item].price.replace(',','').slice(1))) * data.products[item].quantity
      }
      data.total = total
      localStorage.setItem('zysod_cart', JSON.stringify(data));
      UpdateCart()
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(data.products[i].id) === productId) {
          data.products[i].quantity = parseInt(data.products[i].quantity + 1);
          var total =0;
          for(var item in data.products){
            total += (data.products[item].price === 'Price not available'? 0 : parseInt(data.products[item].price.replace(',','').slice(1))) * data.products[item].quantity
          }
          data.total = total              
          localStorage.setItem('zysod_cart', JSON.stringify(data));
          UpdateCart()
        }
      }

    }
  })
  // Single Product Page
  $('.h-addcart').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this).closest('.single-product')
    var productId = parseInt($this.attr('data-product-id'))
    var productName = $this.find('.product-title').text()
    var productImg = $this.attr('data-product-src')
    var productPrice = $this.find('.product-price .price-sale').text()
    var found = data.products.some(function(el){
      return parseInt(el.id) === productId
    })

    if (!found) {
      
      data.items = parseInt(data.items) + 1;          
      data.products.push({
        id: productId,
        name: productName,
        quantity: 1,
        image: productImg,
        price: productPrice              
      });
      var total =0;
      for(var item in data.products){
        total += (data.products[item].price === 'Price not available'? 0 : parseInt(data.products[item].price.replace(',','').slice(1))) * data.products[item].quantity
      }
      data.total = total          
      localStorage.setItem('zysod_cart', JSON.stringify(data));
      
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(data.products[i].id) === productId) {
          data.products[i].quantity = parseInt(data.products[i].quantity + 1);
          var total =0;
          for(var item in data.products){
            total += (data.products[item].price === 'Price not available'? 0 : parseInt(data.products[item].price.replace(',','').slice(1))) * data.products[item].quantity
          }
          data.total = total              
          localStorage.setItem('zysod_cart', JSON.stringify(data));
          
        }
      }

    }

  })
}

function removeFromCart(){
  $(document).on('click','.dropcart__product-remove',function(){        
    var $this = $(this).closest('.dropcart__product')
    var productId = parseInt($this.attr('data-product-id'))
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('zysod_cart'));        
    data.products = $.grep(data.products, function (e) {
      if(e.id == productId){
        data.total-= e.price === 'Price not available'? parseInt(0): (parseInt(e.price.replace(',','').slice(1))*parseInt(e.quantity))
      }
      return e.id != productId;
    }); 
      data.items = data.products.length
      localStorage.setItem('zysod_cart', JSON.stringify(data));          
      
    })
}
```

Comment: Didn't read all of your code, but in your `removeFromCart()` function, you are calling `localStorage.setItem()` instead of `localStorage.removeItem()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus removeItem() will remove the whole "zysod_cart". I am not trying to do that. I am trying to remove just a product only

Comment: As I said, I didn't read all your code, but you need to call `removeItem()` to get things out of `localStorage`.

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(data.products);` before saving data to _localStorage_? Are the deleted products there?

Comment: @Adebayo Please mark correct answers as correct (if they are) using a checkmark. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Looks like in removeFromCart() you are not excluding the one you want to remove. $.grep function is returning true when the deleted product id is equal to the one you want removed, I think it should be return e.id == productId;

Comment: On delete you read from localstorage, you remove the item, and you write to localstorage. When you add new, you use the object when page renders. It does not have the updated since delete does not update that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `data` is read once when `AddToCart` is called.

```js
function AddToCart() {
   var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('zysod_cart'))
   // ...
}
```

> ℹ️ This is because of closures which refer to the top most `data` variable in the upper scope. Read more about closures in [Mozilla Developer Network article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

If you want to solve this you should read `data` from the localStorage each time you change the data, like you do in `removeFromCart()` inside of each `click` event handler:

```
function removeFromCart(){
  $(document).on('click','.dropcart__product-remove',function(){        
    var $this = $(this).closest('.dropcart__product')
    var productId = parseInt($this.attr('data-product-id'))
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('zysod_cart')); 
    // ...
  })
}
```

> ⚠️ You should be noted that several tabs can update the localStorage simultaneously what can cause conflicts. To avoid this it is recommended to use [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker/SharedWorker) to synchronise different tabs.

## Advice

I'd suggest to make your code modular aand supportable, if this is required. You can separate event handling and localStorage manipulation, like this:

```js
class Storage {
  constructor(name, data) {
    this.name = name
    if (data) {
      this.save(data)
    } else {
      if (name in localStorage) {
        this.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name))
      } else {
        this.save({})
      }
    }
  }
  
  save(data) {
    this.data = data
    this.updateStorage()
  }

  updateStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem(this.name, JSON.stringify(this.data))
  }
}

const storage = new Storage('zysod_cart')

function bindAddToCart(storage) {
  $('#addButton').on('click', function () {
     // Copy data
     const data = {...storage.data}
     
     // Add cart logic here ...

     // Save changes

     storage.save(data)
  })
}

function bindRemoveFromCard(storage) {
  $('#removeButton').on('click', function () {
     // Copy data
     const data = {...storage.data}

     // Remove card logic here ...

     // Save changes
     storage.save(data)
  })
}
```

But note that there should be only one instance of `Storage` with the `name` value of `zysod_cart` on the page.